# How do I make this Vintage Electric Tuning Fork run. Pictures and description included

Tags: analog, dc

Short summary of question:

How do I make this electrically driven tuning fork operate?

---

I purchased this old tuning fork from a person who bought it at an estate sale.  He was a doctor and he had also been a professor at Harvard University.

The tuning fork is almost 15 inches long.  The two tongs are 1 1/4" deep 3/4" thick.  There is a coil mounted in the center of the two tongs.

When I apply the current of a 12V car battery to the two terminals and when I say apply I mean I will have one side attached while to one of the posts while I quickly tap the other DC connection.

Depending on the speed in which I tap the alligator clip to the electrical attachment, the coil turns into an electro magnet pulling the tongs inward and then releases the tongs as fast as I pull the wire away from the contact post.

If I touch the contact with the alligator wire at just the right speed and let the electro magnet engage long enough to pull the tongs inward and then the electro magnet releases the tongs to resonate at a certain frequency.

The tuning fork also has a contact on the side of the tuning fork that looks like a set of points that they used to have on John deer lawn mover engines that I had to mow the lawn with on Saturday mornings with.  By adjusting the contact that it moves the stationary contact forward or backward which apply some pressure against the contract which is attached to the tuning fork.

At first when I did not know what volt age powers the tuning fork I gradually worked up to 12 volts using a car battery.  At that time the points were touching each other but when I applied voltage very fast within a 1/4 of a second or less the tuning fork would resonant at a higher pitch when the contacts were touching.

I have backed the contact away from the tuning forks contact to where there is a space as wide as a credit card will slide in and out and the tuning fork will resonant much longer and at a lower tone for a much longer period.

I don't know what the proper voltage is but I am pretty sure that it is higher than 12 volts, due to the fact that it would barely resonant at all while I tried to make it work with the contacts tight like when I purchased it.

I would like to obtain some advice from some of you guys who may know a little more about this type of tuning fork.  I need to build a DC to DC circuit that will do two main things to begin with.

1) First is to determine the Voltage that will be given to the tuning fork.

2) I want to be able to adjust the amount length of the electric DC pulse from the smallest length of time possible up to no more than 1 second I would imagine.

Anything longer just holds the two tongs of the fork bent inward and will not release them to imitate the ping like striking of a regular rubber tuning fork thumping wand.  I would imagine that the circuit that I will have to build will contain one or more Electrolytic capacitors which would need to be among some of the fastest type of capacitors which can release a pulse with the high amperage rate of a 12 volt car battery.

I am not an engineer but I start in January at UNLV Howard Hughes Engineering dept to obtain my electrical engineering degree.

I will be using a 24 volt lead Acid battery to supply the power, in the future I would like to work my way up to making a circuit which can use a regular AC 120 outlet and in the controller box switch it to DC and not have to worry about hauling a 100 lb 24 volt battery around to show this old tuning fork to people.

I am wondering what type of control box they used to use as well as what wave pattern.  I don't know if a regular rectangular DC wave will be best, or a sawtooth wave or possibly a curved wave.

My gut instinct tells me that the sharpest wave with a fine point at the top is going to allow me to be able to see how wide of a range of frequencies the tuning fork will produce.  By what I have seen so far the point connection can really be cranked down very hard against the strip of very rigid thin piece of metal secured to the side of the tuning fork rod.

Back when this Company produced these tuning forks, all of the models in which I have been able to locate were built using a wooden base that would not have been very strong in holding this heavy of a fork.  I dont know why but this one is made out of a beautiful metal very thick mount.  The allen type fastening system does not look like it is from 1910, but their wooden ones do.  Maybe this professor re mounted it?  I dont know.

The resistance of the electro magnet coil insulated wire is 1.2 Ohms when I set my multimeter on 200 ohm which is the lowest setting ohm setting I have.

Based on the information I have provided as well as the pictures I am uploading, is there anyone who can give me some assistance in building the circuit.  I can solder circuit on breadboard very well and have been doing it for years.  But I have to have a set of plans in front of me that shows me what resister to mount where, and that is why I am going to college to learn more about this type of circuit building.

If anyone has any ideas please let me know.

Lance [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please try formatting and edit the sentences so they make sense?  Adding some paragraphs is also nice so it isn't a literal block of text. This is very confusing and hard to follow.

Comment: Try to use the picture upload, it should link to the picture. if not,just up load it to a site like imgur.com and provide the link, we will edit it in.

Comment: You can email me a picture and I'll add it to your post if you wish. Please include link to this question ie  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/194106/need-help-building-a-circuit-to-run-this-vintage-electric-tuning-fork-look-at-th

Comment: Attempt made at layout improvement. May do violence to your intentions in places. I suggest you work on layout to make it say what you intended.

Comment: I would *love* to see this question answered, but without at least a photo and preferably also a sketch of the circuit I don't see how it could be answered.  I'm voting to close this as unclear, but I hope that Lance will come back and add more info so it can be reopened.

Comment: Russell can you email me your email address so you can help me get a pic of this unit on the question board?  My email is LanceLedet@aol.com please email yours and I will send you a pic and an update as to what I have figured out so far

Comment: Here is the first picture, I am sorry about the spelling and the bad explanation this new G6 Samsung has an automatic spelling correction program that puts words in your mouth  even if you spell a word right if you don't select the word it will choose the word it thinks you meant to say I finally figured out how to turn it off, sorry about that.  I will take more pics when I get home tonight.

Comment: That coil is probably not designed for more than 12V. I think more like 2-6V. The pointy bit is probably for recording the wave (eg. on a moving chart). The contact is for generating sine waves for standing waves. A circuit to generate waves without the contact could  be built with a sensor such as an optical or Hall sensor. Possibly without a sensor too.

Comment: try wiring the contact in series with the coil, stick a head-lamp in series as a ballast, and connect the whole lot to your 12V supply.

Comment: Hello Spehro, I thought the coil was going to be for lower power as well, but I started a a AAA, then moved up through the following batteries AA,C,D,6 volt and a 9 volt battery and nothing at all would happen with any of those voltages, only when I moved up to 12 volts car battery with 80 amps did the coil energize strong enough to make the tuning fork resonant.  When i do build a circuit I would like to try voltage that low with amps that I can increase, but so far just using the voltages you recommend didn't do anything.  Thank you for your input though.

Comment: HI Jason, one side of the wire coming from the opposite side of the coil goes to the adjustable contact post that is in a position sitting next to the tuning forks side, so I could not wire it the way you are asking me to.  The coil itself it's wire on one side feeds the contact that is mounted to the base.  It is set up really weird.

Comment: Can anyone recommend a very good top of the line program for designing circuits on the computer and actually trying the circuits out and making sure they work by using the computer program to show the wave pattern that the circuit will produce as well as the voltage and amperage increase as I adjust the circuit as I adjust it on a computer simulation?  I don't know what programs we will be using in school but I would like to get familiar with one now to get ahead, and I can't think of a better circuit to start with.  Any suggestions guys?

Comment: You have the tuning fork mentioned on the page: https://media.vwr.com/interactive/publications/VWR_sargent_welch_2014/files/assets/basic-html/page304.html  It requires a 6Volt powersupply.  I expect your problems were caused by using too small a battery.  The tuning fork will take a lot of current, which your little batteries couldn't supply.  The one recommended by the manufacturer supplies 6Volts at up to 5Amperes.

Comment: If you look closely, you will see that the knob to the side of the tuning fork is connected to the coil.  This is the interruptor that makes the fork vibrate rather than just moving once when you apply power.  Adjust it so that it opens when the fork vibrates (smack the fork and watch for a gap.)  Once you get it to open when the fork vibrates, apply 6Volts to the terminals and it should go into sustained vibration.  You can then control the amplitude of the vibration by turning the knob.

Comment: The recommended power supply: https://www.sargentwelch.com/store/catalog/product.jsp?catalog_number=WLS1799-16&utm_source=flipbook&utm_medium=digital%2Bcatalog&utm_campaign=vwr%2Bsargent_welch%2B2014-2015

Comment: More photos here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pira-chat/JsZvV-zsugs

Comment: Voted to reopen after @Lance posted pictures and added info.

Comment: I have located a book from 1918, it shows this exact model of tuning fork, it also goes into detail and tells what this tuning fork is not only used for, but it also list an unbelievable amount of information which has either been repressed or deliberately kept out of future books after this year in 1918.  I got a copy of a 2nd book that really shows some technology that will litteraly shock you.  I can not believe the amount of information that I have uncovered, just by trying to find information on this extremely old tuning fork.

Comment: what I am going to need is a circuit that I can not only adjust the voltage going to the electro magnet between the tongs, but I also need to be able to adjust the time in which the electro magnet coil is turned on and off so many times a second.  I have read, if I can build a circuit that will reverse the electro magnets poles fast enough that the circuit will constantly allow me to adjust the speed in which it reverse the magnetic coils poles fast enough from pulling to pushing the tuning fork to obtain frequencies that are not usually available on a regular tuning fork that size, any ideas?

Comment: I am going to scan the pages that talk about this exact tuning fork, the book is from 198 so it is a pencil sketch, but I am trying to figure out a way to get them on this post for all of you to read.  Thank you guys for bearing with me, I have been trying to locate information on this fork as we're as register for the engineering University here in Las Vegas.

Comment: JRE, is there any way to build this power supply from scratch?  if I purchased every unit that they sell, it would be close to 1000 or more dollars, anybody have any ideas, as to a circuit that would allow me to adjust the frequency as well as the power?

Comment: JRE, could you please email me, at LasVegasLabs@aol.com

Comment: According to the book I found made in 1918.  There are multiple ways to make this power supply, and I mean many ways.  I really need to figure out how to upload the pages on this book, because the book shows that you can use the tuning fork itself, to be the oscillation coil which is sold separately at the website you gave me.  I have researched this exact model Bach to a model that Keely used to disintegrate granite, and bore a hole in a granite wall some 40 feet within a matter of 15 minutes.

Comment: All you really need is ANY 6Volt DC power supply that can put out up to 5Amperes.  The trick then is to properly adjust the contacts so that the tuning fork itself will drive the coil.  That is the whole trick.  The tuning fork is a mechanical oscillator that mechanically interrupts the coil drive circuit.  That lets the power supply keep retriggering the tuning fork and keeps the oscillation going.  No complicated electronics needed.  Just power and  the contact on the side.

Comment: You cannot really adjust the frequency.  The tuning fork will only vibrate at one frequency.  Driving it at any other rate will be difficult (at best) to impossible.  It is also not reasonable to try.  The whole point of the device is to generate mechanical vibrations at a specific and stable rate to be used in certain physics experiments.

Comment: Thanks for the information JRE, do you happen to know where I can get a power supply that I can set to 6 volts and 5 amps?  I would like to find a power supply that I could use on other projects as well, I don't need anything extremely fancy, but a digital readout would be nice or at least a Guage showing the amps and volt output.  Do you happen to know where I can get a good quality power supply that would run this unit as well as other projects that I will be doing in engineering school starting in January 18th?

Comment: JRE do you have an email address that I can send you about 4 scanned pages of a book I located that had been scanned before the library was told to shred it?  it shows the exact same tuning fork with only 2 modifications.  But the two modifications allow you to use the same tuning fork to change its resonant frequency.  It seemed so simple that a child could have drawn this picture but it makes perfect sense.  there is one modification on the front of the tuning fork that I just want to make sure I am understanding it correctly.  would you mind looking at a couple of pages of drawing

Comment: Hey JRE, thanks for the information you have given me.  I am going to have to figure out how to build this particular power supply, using my large scrap pile that I keep for such things.  I  am just starting engineering school on January 18th, but the research I have been doing that resembles this exact tuning fork goes back as far as 1907 where I located a drawing in a book which showed attachments to fork itself also to the coil, and how to change the resonating frequency using the same fork.  if I can get your email I would like to scan them as email them to you.

Comment: I am going to try to build a DC power supply that has the specs you shared with me.  I understand what you mean about the adjustment contact, but when you take a look at a couple of pages in this very old book.  You will see what I am trying to explain.  you can email me at LasVegasLabs@aol.com to give me your email address.  just address it to Lance

Comment: Hey JRE,           I went to that Sargent Welch and sent them an email that I wanted to purchase the control box from them.  They sent me an email back stating that they no longer carried the product.  And they also did not carry any other products for the tuning fork.

Comment: ALSO JRE,  Do you know where I can get a set of plans to build a circuit board, that has the same settings as that box does when you click on it?  That control box if I understand it correctly, it sends out AC and DC voltage with 5 amps of each type at the same time.  Could you take a look at the specs on thar power supply.  And tell me if I am reading it correctly.  I have never heard of using AC and DC at the same time on any device, and I have no idea how to build such a device.  Have you got any suggestions?

Comment: ALSO JRE,  Do you know where I can get a set of plans to build a circuit board, that has the same settings as that box does when you click on it?  That control box if I understand it correctly, it sends out AC and DC voltage with 5 amps of each type at the same time.  Could you take a look at the specs on thar power supply.  And tell me if I am reading it correctly.  I have never heard of using AC and DC at the same time on any device, and I have no idea how to build such a device.  Have you got any suggestions?

Comment: You only need a simply DC power supply the puts out 6Volts DC at up to 5Amperes.

Comment: I understand that I just thought that the red power supply that you showed me said that it would run on 6 volts 5 amps DC or AC  and I did not know of any power supply that could make one with both the Ac and DC being 6volt and 5 amps each and I was curious why it could run on both

Comment: Thanks JRE but what I am trying to explain is that the sear gentle Welch product list had that red power supply remember?? It had 6 volts 5 amps AC on one side and 6 volts 5 amps on the other side.  And a selector switch to select which one you wanted to use.  I can't find anyone who sells the same kind of power supply.  I just wanted to know if you knew what the difference would be on how either the dc or AC source would act different during the ossiciolating of the tunning fork?

Comment: The only thing I can add is that I looked up the sear gentle Welch website and I was so excited I planned on maxing out my credit cards purchasing the power supply to tune it.

Comment: But after sending them an email wanting to purchase the 6 volt 5 amp dc and ac power supply in which you could use each to run the unit the water they told my wife, but they looked it up for me to purchase online and you guessed it.  They are out or the power supplies as well and don't know when that will have more. So I am hoping I can find a power supply online that shoes and engineering student rheostat easiest way to build one.  That's all I have left to do it guess.